# Magento2: How to check if cron job is working or not?

Tags: magento2, cron, cronjobs

How can I check if my cron job is created or not?
I have created a module that is creating shipment of orders with status processing,
my question is how can I check if the cron job is working or not?
how can I debug my cron file?

Comment: Try to install following extension, its very good for checking cronjobs,
https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-cron-schedule/ Thanks & Regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first, check if the cron job is installed or not if not then run these commands in your project root dir

```
sudo php bin/magento cron:install
```

then run this command to create cron jobs

```
sudo php bin/magento cron:run
```

finally, check your cron job on your cron table **cron_schedule**

also, you can check cron logs in

> var/log/magento.cron.logs

Comment: is it  php bin/magento cron:status command available?

Comment: I think so it's not

Comment: you are right @S.Shah

Answer (score 3):

You can check all the cron jobs in any status in the table `cron_schedule`:

[image: cron_schedule table view]

Inside you can look for your job name in the `job_code` column. Other way is to use next query:

```
SELECT * FROM `cron_schedule` WHERE job_code = 'your_job_code' ORDER BY created_at DESC
```

Note: change the **your_job_code** value to your job code.

More information about cron error logging could be found in [dev docs](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-cron.html#logging):

> **Logging**.
>
> All cron job information has moved from system.log into a
> separate cron.log. By default, the cron information can be found at
> <install_directory>/var/log/cron.log. All exceptions from cron jobs
> are logged by
> \Magento\Cron\Observer\ProcessCronQueueObserver::execute.
>
> In addition to being logged in cron.log:
>
> Failed jobs with ERROR and MISSED statuses are logged to the
> <install_directory>/var/log/support_report.log.
>
> Jobs with an ERROR status are always logged as CRITICAL in
> <install_directory>/var/log/exception.log.
>
> Jobs with a MISSED status are logged as INFO in the
> <install_directory>/var/log/debug.log directory (developer mode only).
>
> All cron data is also written to the cron_schedule table in the
> Magento database. The table provides a history of cron jobs,
> including:
>
> - Job ID and code
> - Status
> - Created date
> - Scheduled date
> - Executed date
> - Finished date
>
> To see records in the table, log in to the Magento
> database on the command line and enter `SELECT * from cron_schedule;`.

Answer (score 2):

You can run cron job with below command.

```
php bin/magento cron:run
```

Also, run the command from the root,

```
crontab -l
```

List all cron if you have cron otherwise display default cron.

REF: https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Admin-Configuration/How-to-make-sure-your-Magento-cron-job-is-running/td-p/85552